# Cannot delete object in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

When I try to delete an instance of model called `place` I get the error below. The model has an attribute with the following type: `string`,`datetime`, `int4range`, `boolean`, `numrange`, `integer`, `text`, `decimal`, `float`.

I'm using rails 4.2.4, ruby 2.2.1, pg 9.4.5

[image]

Comment: have you defined the destroy or delete action in your cancan?

Comment: I did not, but I let admin manage all like so `can :manage, :all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this problem once and, in my case, i found it happen because Rails Admin try to show the relationship. This get err along the way.

I solve this problem by overriding the rails_admin show delete view
just create
`views/rais_admin/main/_delete_notice.html.haml`
and put

```
- object = delete_notice

%li{style: 'display:block; margin-top:10px'}
  %span.label.label-default= @abstract_model.pretty_name
  - wording = object.send(@model_config.object_label_method)
  - if show_action = action(:show, @abstract_model, object)
    = link_to(wording, url_for(action: show_action.action_name, model_name: @abstract_model.to_param, id: object.id), class: 'pjax')
  - else
    = wording
  %ul
    - @abstract_model.each_associated_children(object) do |association, child|
      -#- unless child.kind_of?(String) || child.kind_of?(ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging)
      - if child.kind_of?(ActiveRecord::Base)
        %li
          - child_config = RailsAdmin.config(child)
          = @abstract_model.model.human_attribute_name association.name
          - wording = child.send(child_config.object_label_method)
          - if child.id && (show_action = action(:show, child_config.abstract_model, child))
            = link_to(wording, url_for(action: show_action.action_name, model_name: child_config.abstract_model.to_param, id: child.id), class: 'pjax')
          - else
            = wording
```

the line `- if child.kind_of?(ActiveRecord::Base)` prevent the further checking on model attributes, which causing `undefined method model for nil:NilClass` in your error log